# Oracle Apex 20 - REST source action on column in interactive report

Tags: rest, oracle-apex-20.1, oracle-rest-data-services

I am trying to setup a form with table report and use REST sources only.

Currently I have a Form and Interactive report setup. It uses a rest source with dynamic items. i.e:

```
http://source/asm/instances/:group
```

where `:group` is then searchable from the form.

Now the columns returned are all user related, but one item I want to be able to set via the REST API. So assuming I entered a group and get the following results:

```
group | name | surname | status
ABC   | Dan  | Murray  | inactive
ABC   | Mary | Swanson | active
```

The REST Source has a function to activate/deactivate the `status` remotely on the tool. i.e

```
http://source/asm/instances/ABC/dan/activate
```

and

```
http://source/asm/instances/ABC/dan/deactivate
```

Now I need to modify the status column to be in a list form with two options, activate/deactivate. This is where the issue comes in. When either of the two items are selected, it needs to use the relevant REST source as posted above and post to the tool, meaning it will activate/deactivate on the fly.
I have spent the entire weekend searching and trying and I just cannot find a way to do this.

The closest I got so far was to create a link, but that just routes me to the URL which is not what I need.

I really hope someone is able to help me here as I am struggling big time.

Comment: Did you tried to add to buttons which will call a PL/SQL Processes, and they should call the API endpoint. Maybe? Create a test enviroment, please.

Comment: @davidm, I would need to create those buttons inside of each column then. A group can contain 50 users of which you need to submit the button for each user. If that is possible, then please elaborate on how that can be done?

Comment: Never tried to do it but I do have an idea on where to start from. It is easy to create a button on every row and attach an DA to it. How do you differ between users (url param or json or http header tag)?

Comment: I will create a test on my own...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I solved your problem, give it a try. :)

##### Version

Oracle Application Express 20.2.0.00.20

##### Solution

I suppose you know how to set the **REST Data Source (DS)** and create an Interactive report with the data fetched from de DS, so I will skip those steps.

1. Go to your Interactive report definition and under settings find **Local Post Processing** and set the values:

- Type: **SQL Query**
- SQL Query:

```sql
select 
    /*leave all the columns fetched from the DS*/
    --
    -- Add this column 
    '<a class="rest-button-status" data-id="'||<PRIMARY-KEY>||'">Link</a>' BUTTON
  from #APEX$SOURCE_DATA#
```

2. Go to the **BUTTON** column definition, under **Security** disable **Escape special characters**.
3. Add a new hidden item and call it P1_NEW.
4. Run the application and you should see your Interactive Report with a link in the last column.
5. Now add an Dynamic action defined as (name it however you want):

[image]

6. To this DA add two True actions:

- First - Set Value

[image]

```js
// copy paste code
$(this.triggeringElement).attr('data-id')
```

- Second - Execute Server-side Code (PL/SQL)

**EDIT** Page Items to submit - P1_NEW

```sql
-- code
DECLARE
    l_clob  CLOB;
    -- I added a parameter PK
    v_url VARCHAR2(2000) := 'http://xxxxx:8080/ords/xxxx/xxxxxx/test-apex/deactivate?PK=';
BEGIN
    L_CLOB := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST(
        -- I added a parameter PK
        p_url                  => v_url||:P1_NEW,
        p_http_method          => 'POST' -- or GET or other
    );
END;
```

The toggling system (activate/deactivate) is up to you, maybe the best solution is to have one endpoint and then the DS controls the status.

**EDIT - based on comments**
Here are some screenshot of the second DA:

1. Add another action to the DA.

[image]

2. Define an `Execute Server-side Code` or `Execute PL/SQL Code` (the name of the action depends on the Oracle APEX version you have)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Let me go through the steps and see what it does. I will get back to you asap.

Comment: on the PL/SQL Server side condition, I get `ORA-06550: line 1, column 106: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: ( - +`

Comment: Remove the comment maybe or newline

Comment: Oh! I you also need to add the P1_NEW as item to submit.

Comment: PL/SQL code is a no go. I rewrote the code manually even and no comments it same error. I even did `set define on`

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the action, code and error

Comment: Screenshots added to question. Also note that I tried just doing a normal `DECLARE`, `START` and `END;` in the PL/SQL field with a static value and action to test and I keep getting the error. It seems like Apex does just not want to declare anything on the server side conditions.

Comment: In the screen shot where is the action declaration? I can see the set value but the PL/SQL?

Comment: See screenshot I added now.

Comment: I see..... I think you misunderstood :) I will add some sceenshots

Comment: ok, thanks, was not clear on that one. So the error is gone, but the button is not clickable. So it shows as a link, but you cannot click on it.

Comment: If you set the event correctly everything should work.

Comment: Can you explain to me how do you it is not clickable?

Comment: Just as you see the `manage` in that screenshot, that is it, it is a plain text box, so you cannot click it to change the status, even though it displays as blue like a link usually does. Everything is setup exactly as you mentioned. I will go through it again now and make sure I missed nothing.

Comment: Thats not plain text, that's an anchor. Second if the anchor tag doesn't have an href you won't see the pointer change. If you want the pointer to change you need to use some CSS. So this is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: No, I understand that, what I mean is that it is not clickable. If I click on manage nothing happens, it is like a plane text box. I am just testing something else quickly using some if statements.

Comment: Yeah probably, I will try and fix it, thanks. No need for me to waste any more of your time. Thanks for the help.